# Docker Could not build image from Maven

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-image

I need your help I got project to do and I don't know how to start it ,I hope do you are can help me .

and this repository: https://github.com/spring-guides/top-spring-boot-docker

First thing I built a Dockerfile According to README, I make Dockefile from repository to my host

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw install -DskipTests

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} target/application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/application.jar extract --destination target/extracted

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
VOLUME /tmp
USER demo
ARG EXTRACTED=/workspace/app/target/extracted
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=build ${EXTRACTED}/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build ${EXTRACTED}/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=build ${EXTRACTED}/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build ${EXTRACTED}/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-noverify","-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1","-Dspring.main.lazy-initialization=true","org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

After I build the Dockerfile

```
C:\Users\LS\Desktop\Job\Test>docker build -t myorg/myapp .

    [+] Building 6.4s (13/19)
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
     => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8-jdk-alpine                                            3.6s
     => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
     => => transferring context: 897B                                                                                  0.0s
     => [stage-1 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:8-jdk-alpine@sha256:94792824df2df33402f201713f932b58cb9de94a0cd5  0.0s
     => CACHED [stage-1 2/7] RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo                                           0.0s
     => CACHED [stage-1 3/7] WORKDIR application                                                                       0.0s
     => CACHED [build 2/9] WORKDIR /workspace/app                                                                      0.0s
     => CACHED [build 3/9] COPY mvnw .                                                                                 0.0s
     => CACHED [build 4/9] COPY .mvn .mvn                                                                              0.0s
     => CACHED [build 5/9] COPY pom.xml .                                                                              0.0s
     => CACHED [build 6/9] COPY src src                                                                                0.0s
     => ERROR [build 7/9] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw install -DskipTests                           2.7s
    ------
     > [build 7/9] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 ./mvnw install -DskipTests:
    #13 1.665 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    #13 1.898 [INFO]
    #13 1.898 [INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
    #13 1.898 [INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    #13 1.898 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    #13 2.166 [INFO]
    #13 2.167 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
    #13 2.454 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    #13 2.454 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
    #13 2.460 [INFO] Copying 1 resource
    #13 2.492 [INFO] Copying 0 resource
    #13 2.494 [INFO]
    #13 2.494 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
    #13 2.608 [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    #13 2.612 [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /workspace/app/target/classes
    #13 2.683 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #13 2.683 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    #13 2.683 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #13 2.685 [INFO] Total time:  1.040 s
    #13 2.685 [INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-24T11:36:26Z
    #13 2.685 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #13 2.687 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
    #13 2.687 [ERROR]
    #13 2.687 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    #13 2.687 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    #13 2.687 [ERROR]
    #13 2.688 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    #13 2.688 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    ------
    executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./mvnw install -DskipTests]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: you could use jib to build it. Google provides a maven plugin for it

Comment: Maven fails with "Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17" - what version of the jdk are you using?

Comment: he is using openjdk:8

Comment: weird, the java project you referenced seems to use java 8, and your base image is java 8, but it complains about 17, did you change the java version of the project?

Comment: You have JDK 8 in your Docker container, but your Maven build is configured to compile for Java 17. That's not going to work, the Java compiler in JDK 8 cannot compile code for Java 17. Either use JDK 17 in your Docker container, or modify your Maven project so that it works with JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

Please look more at line, you could provide a correct jdk version.
`#13 2.687 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

The javac in the docker image is too Old to be able to compile Java 17 code

Either convert to java 8 or use a java17-based image.

Comment: Thank for your comment, I edited  the Dockerfile to JDK17 and  build it , after  than I tried to run the image and I get this message again .  

[C:\Users\LS\Desktop\Job\Test>docker run -p 9090:9090 myorg/myapp
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app.jar]

Comment: It is most likely invalid or corrupt then.   That can have many reasons. I would look inside the container and investigate `/app.jar`.

Comment: Also this looks needlessly complicated for a relatively simple compile-and-package dockerfile.